# Set of primes in the spectrum of a rational number.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $x \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}$ (numerator and denominator are in the reduced form). Can we comment anything about the set $\left\{  \left\lfloor nx \right\rfloor \; : \; n \in \mathbb{N}  \right\}$? Is there any structure in this set of integers especially the possible set of prime integers?

Also, can anyone point me toward the topics in number theory which deals with such kind of problems? Any hint will be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, sticks me the must important thing is how *big* $x$ is.  If $x \le 1$ then that set is $\mathbb N$.  Try to play and see what it may be for other values.  For example if $x = 7\frac 35$ then set is $\{7,15, 22,30,38, 45,53,60,68,76,....\}$ Do you see any pattern? Does it have anything to do with denominator.  Notice we ahve $\{7\frac 35, 14\frac 65, 21,\frac 95, 28\frac {12}5, 35 \frac {15}5, .....\}$.

Comment: I don't get why you mention that $x$ does not need to be in the reduced form. You not talking at all about numerator and denominator, only about $x$ itself.

Comment: W.l.o.g. $x=p/q$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$. If $s_n=\lfloor nx\rfloor$ then we have $s_{n+q}=s_n+p$. Therefore the set consists of $q$ residue classes of integers modulo $p$. Dirichlet's theorem of equidistribution of primes will then say something about the percentage of primes in this sequence if you can tell how many of those residue classes are coprime to $p$. In @fleablood's example we see that $2$ out of $5$ residue classes are coprime to $38$, and therefore the fraction of primes appearing in that sequence is asymptotically $2/\phi(38)=1/9$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Among these $q$ residue classes, can we claim that there exist at least one integer from the set $\left\{ \left\lfloor nx \right\rfloor \; : \; n \in \{0,1,\dots, q-1 \} \right\}$ which is co-prime to $p$? If this were true, then there will be infinite number of prime of the form $np+$integer from above set. It seems to be the case when I try it on particular examples, but I am not able to show how this is true in general case.

Comment: They form a complete residue class $\mod q$.   So one if then equiv to $p-1$ and if $p\ne q-1$ one of the is congruent $p+1$ or $p+2$ and $p-2$ if $p$ is odd etc.

Comment: @fleablood Could you please explain it a bit? The incorrect sentence is making it harder to understand anything.

Comment: Related question from same OP: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4123775/integers-co-prime-to-p-in-the-set-left-left-lfloor-nx-right-rfloor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m = \lfloor x \rfloor $.  Let $r = x-m$ so $0\le r < 1$.  $q$ is rational so let $j,k \in \mathbb N$ so that $\gcd(j,k) = 1$ and $r = \frac jk$.  In other words..... Let $x = m + \frac jk$ were $m$ is integers and $\frac jk$ is a non-negative rational in reduced terms less than $1$.

$ nx  =  nm + nj\cdot \frac 1k  = nm + q_n + \frac {a_n}k$ where $q_n = \lfloor {nj}\rfloor$ and $a_n \equiv nj \pmod k; 0 \le a < k$

So $\lfloor nx\rfloor= nm + q_n$ where $q_n = \lfloor {nj}\rfloor$.

....

Anyhow,... As $j, k$ are relatively prime $nj; n=1,...,k$ form a complete residue system $\mod k$. And $b'_n = \lfloor \frac {nj}k\rfloor;n=1,...,k$ (note $b'_1= 0$ and $b'_k = j$ always) will be a  sequence of $k$ integers.  We can define $b_{n+k} = b_n$ to extend this sequence to be repeating sequence of period $k$.

So  $nx =  nm + j\lfloor \frac nk\rfloor + b_n + \frac {a_n}k$ and $\lfloor nx\rfloor = nm + j\lfloor \frac nk\rfloor + b_n$

I gave, in the comments, and example of $x = 7\frac 35 = \frac {38}5$.

In this case $m=\lfloor \frac {38}5\rfloor = 7; r= \frac 35; j= 3; k=5; a_n \equiv 3,6,9,12,15 \pmod 5$ and $a_n = 3,1,4,2,0$ and $b_n = 0,1,1,2,3$

And $\lfloor n\cdot 7\frac 35\rfloor= 7n + 3\lfloor \frac n5\rfloor + b_n$.

Example:  $\lfloor 139\cdot 7\frac 35\rfloor =$

$\lfloor 139\cdot 7 + (27\cdot 5 + 4)\frac 35 \rfloor =$

$\lfloor 139\cdot 7 + 27\cdot 3 + \frac {4\times 3}5\rfloor =$

$\lfloor 139 \cdot 7 + 27\cdot 3 + \frac {2\cdot 5 + 2}5\rfloor = $

$\lfloor 139 \cdot 7 + 27\cdot 3 + 2 + \frac 25\rfloor =$

$139\cdot 7 + 27\cdot 3 + 2$

Where $7 = \lfloor x \rfloor = m$. and $3 =$ the numerator of $\frac 35 = $ numerator of $x-m = j$ and $2=b_{4}$ (as $139\equiv 4 \pmod 5$).