# Integers co-prime to $p$ in the spectrum of a rational number.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $x=p/q$ be a positive rational number (not an integer) in the reduced form. Is it necessary that the set of integers $\left\{ \left\lfloor nx \right\rfloor \; : \; n \in \{0,1,\dots, q-1 \} \right\} $ will contain integers co-prime to $p$? How do we prove this this result?

Comment: Who is x? Not specified

Comment: Certainly false if $q=1$. [This comment was posted before OP edited to rule out $q=1$.]

Comment: Related question from same OP: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4121668/set-of-primes-of-the-form-left-left-lfloor-nx-right-rfloor-n-in